# Installing Ubuntu on formated hard drive

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04, ubiquity

I am currently using Windows XP and I wanted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows using live CD. But every time I started the installation, Ubiquity would freeze on 'install alongside' screen. I have 2 partitions C (in which Windows is installed) and D on my hard drive. When I formatted the D partition and tried to install Ubuntu, Ubiquity did not detect any of the partitions.

I just want to know that if I format both the partitions and then try to install Ubuntu, will Ubuntu get installed without any problem as encountered by Ubiquity stated above or how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you tell which Ubuntu version are you installing? It may help to try the latest (13.04) version.

Comment: ubuntu 13.04 and in ubuntu 12.10 as well...

Comment: When you say *format both the partitions* do you mean create the necessary partitions for Ubuntu **only**?

Comment: no i meant deleting all the partitions and installing only ubuntu on hard drive.....

Answer (score 0):

Try [booting Ubuntu from USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) or [CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD). Then, [just install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest). Recommended 13.04, Raring Ringtail.

Comment: thats what i am having problem with...''ubiquity''
i installed linux mint 14 cinnamon and it installed perfectly. but i want ubuntu 13.04.
is there a way i could use ubiquity in linux mint 14 to install ubuntu ?

Comment: Ubiquity is already on the USB/CD installer. Just boot from USB/CD and you will get the Ubiquity installer working, and installing perfectly.